# Ошибка заполнение коллекции ArrayList методом .add

Tags: java

Типа крестики/нолики.

Должно происходить рандомное заполнение ячеек массива символом 'Х'. '.' - свободная ячейка. Проверяется соответствие ячейки на пустоту, если пуста, пишется 'X'. Если не пуста, делать снова. Если массив заполнен - прервать выполнение. В методе fill происходит заполнение двух массивов пустыми клетками ('.'). Метод generateRandomXO заполняет искомый массив 'Х'. Индекс заполнения берется из массива2, размер которого сокращается. Один лист является массивом индексов второго. Условие окончания цикла - нулевой размер массива индексов.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dz {
    public static ArrayList cells = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList cells2 = new ArrayList<>();
    static int size = 9;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dz xo = new Dz();
    xo.fill(cells);
    xo.indexFill(cells2);
    generateRandomXO();
}

private static void generateRandomXO() {
    int index;
    do {
        index = (int) (Math.random() * (cells2.size()));
        if (cells2.size() == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (cells.get(index).equals('X')) {
            continue;
        } else if (cells.get(index).equals('.')) {
            cells.set(cells2.get(index), 'X');
            cells2.remove(index);
            System.out.println(cells);
        }
    } while (cells2.size() == 0);
}

void fill(ArrayList cells) {
    this.cells = cells;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                
        cells.add('.');                                         
    }
}
void indexFill(ArrayList cells) {
    this.cells = cells;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {               
        cells.add(i);                                         
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В методе `fill` **HE** происходит заполнение двух массивов пустыми клетками ('.').

Comment: Если массив пустой, то вот это выражение `for (int i = 0; i < cells.size() - 1; i++)` превращается в `for (int i = 0; i < -1; i++)`, а значит цикл не сделает ни одной итерации. Но и сам цикл не имеет смысла, так как если массив не пустой, то цикл просто  будет в него бесконечно добавлить элементы, пока не кончится память.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Ошибки как таковой нет. Есть неправильный алгоритм.
Мне нужно полное заполнение массива cells символом 'X'. У меня лишь частичное.

Comment: `Код крашится на этапе заполнения коллекции чарами` как нет ошибки?

Comment: Извините я не поправил описание.
В процессе ответов код правился и некоторые ошибки я исправил.
В общем должно быть заполнение одного массива крестиками, при этом индекс должен браться из другого массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясните словами, что должен делать этот код

```
void fill(ArrayList cells) {                                    //ошибка ТУТ
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.size() - 1; i++) {                //размер массива 0
        cells.add('.');                                         //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

когда в функцию передается (например, пустой) массив.

---

В коде, который Вы показали, не может быть `NullPointerException`.

А-а, `NullPointerException` - в `generateRandomXO`.

---

Зачем нужны статические члены класса `cells` и `cells2` и локальные переменные с такими же именами в  `main`?

Начнем с этого:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dz xo = new Dz();
    /*ArrayList<Character>*/ cells = new ArrayList<>(); // !!!
    xo.fill(cells);
    /*ArrayList<Character>*/ cells2 = new ArrayList<>(); // !!!
    xo.fill(cells2);
    generateRandomXO();
}
```

Comment: Так вот я и спрашиваю, ПОЧЕМУ массив пустой, ведь я его и пытаюсь заполнить.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev Объясните словами, что должен делать этот код.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev Массив пустой, потому что Вы его создали (в нем ничего нет) и передали в эту функцию.