# Проблема с заполнение массива Arraylist

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, arraylist

Уже была похожая проблема
[Ошибка заполнение коллекции ArrayList методом .add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197821/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-arraylist-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-add)
, но снова не понимаю в чем дело.

Есть пара классов:

```
/**
* Основной класс, с инициализацией полей.
*/

    public class Main {
        Scanner scanner;
        PlayerManager playerManager;
    
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main start = new Main();
            PlayerManager manager = new PlayerManager();
            Count count = new Count(0);
            manager.addPlayer(start.playerInvitation(), count);
            manager.addPlayer(start.playerInvitation(), count);
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.println(manager.players);
            System.out.println(manager.players.get(0).id);
            System.out.println(manager.players.get(1).name);
            start.runGame();

    }

    void runGame() {
        Field plate = new Field();
        plate.fillTheField();               //инициализация поля отображаемого для игроков
        plate.fillTheSpace();               //поле для вычислений
        plate.printFields();


//        mainCycle(plate);
    }

    /**
     * Основной цикл игры между 2 пользователями
     */

//
//    void mainCycle(Field plate) {
//        do {
//
//
//        } while (field.space.size() != 0);
//    }

    /**
     * приглашения пользователя
     */


    String playerInvitation() {
        System.out.println("Введите имя игрока: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        return name;
    }


}
```

Другой класс:

```
/**
 * класс игровое поле
 */
public class Field {
    char[][] field;                                     //видимое поле 1
    ArrayList<Integer> space;                         //альтернативное внутреннее поле 2

    Field() {
        char[][] field = new char[3][3];                // 1
        this.field = field;
        ArrayList<Integer> space = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
        this.space = space;  // 2
    }

    void fillTheField() {                               // 1
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                this.field[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
        }
    
       void fillTheSpace() {
//        for (Integer counter : space) {
//            counter++;
//        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            space.add(i);
        }
    }
    
    
        void printFields() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             

   System.out.print(this.field[i][j] + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print(space + "\t");
        }
    }

    void markX(int i, int j) {
        this.field[i][j] = 'X';
    }

    void markO(int i, int j) {
        this.field[i][j] = '0';
    }

}
```

В результате выполнения вот этой строки

plate.fillTheSpace();        (метод runGame/класс Main)

хочу получить массив цифр, по типу : [1], [2], [3], [4]   .....

А получаю : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3,   ......

Вроде массив создан и проинициализирован. Что не так с методом fillThePlace? Т.е. как заполнить список из 9-ти элементов 9-ю цифрами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.print(space.get(i) + "\t");
                              ^^^^^^^
    }
```

Comment: Ну точно. Вот же я слепошара. Большое спасибо.